# How to run a function when one button is clicked without changing other id values

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 columns with same ID, each have 1 button. How to run a function when one button is clicked without changing other ID values?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<!--- column 1 ------> 
    <div class="column nature">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="Jane" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="title" style="text-align:center;">SCA5-01</p>
                    <div  style="text-align:center;">
                        <div id="hrg" style="font-size:5vw;font-weight:bold;">2000</div> 
                        <div id="per">/500</div>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:100%;margin:0px 5%;display:block;">
                    <div style="font-size:2vw;">
                        <br>Spect :
                        <br>- New
                        <br>- Fresh
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                <div style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;text-align:center;">
                    <input id="jmlh" type="number" value="500" style="width:50%;"> 
                    <button onclick="price();">chek</button>
                </div>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="button">Order</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--- column 1 ------>  
        <div class="column nature">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="Jane" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="title" style="text-align:center;">SCA5-01</p>
                    <div  style="text-align:center;">
                        <div id="hrg" style="font-size:5vw;font-weight:bold;">2000</div> 
                        <div id="per">/500</div>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:100%;margin:0px 5%;display:block;">
                    <div style="font-size:2vw;">
                        <br>Spect :
                        <br>- New
                        <br>- Fresh
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                <div style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;text-align:center;">
                    <input id="jmlh" type="number" value="500" style="width:50%;"> 
                    <button onclick="price();">chek</button>
                </div>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="button">Order</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my function:

```
<script>
function price(){
var qty = document.getElementById("jmlh").value;
var prc = Math.ceil((1000000 / qty)/100)*100;
document.getElementById("hrg").innerHTML = prc;
document.getElementById("per").innerHTML = "/" + qty;
}
</script>
```

The problem here is that function only runs on 'column 1' & doesn't work on 'column 2'.

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: `id` should be unique in the same document. Use classes or other attributes instead of `id`

Comment: what if the column is more than 2?

Comment: why same id? ids are supposed to be unique always

Comment: it doesn't matter if there are 2 or 1000 columns, you can use class and access each of them by their index, Check documentation [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: I don't know what to replace. please help

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be unique in the same document. Use classes or other attributes instead of `id`.

If you want centralized function to handle clicks, submit the clicked element itself to that function, so it would know which column was clicked:

```
    <div class="column nature">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="Jane" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="title" style="text-align:center;">SCA5-01</p>
                    <div  style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="hrg" style="font-size:5vw;font-weight:bold;">2000</div> 
                        <div class="per">/500</div>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:100%;margin:0px 5%;display:block;">
                    <div style="font-size:2vw;">
                        <br>Spect :
                        <br>- New
                        <br>- Fresh
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                <div style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;text-align:center;">
                    <input class="jmlh" type="number" value="500" style="width:50%;"> 
                    <button onclick="price(this);">chek</button>
                </div>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="button">Order</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
function price(el){
const elContainer = el.closest(".container");// find parent
var qty = elContainer.querySelector(".jmlh").value;
var prc = Math.ceil((1000000 / qty)/100)*100;
elContainer.querySelector(".hrg").innerHTML = prc;
elContainer.querySelector(".per").innerHTML = "/" + qty;
}
```

Note, that all `id` were replaced by `class` attribute and in javascript instead of searching entire document with `document.getElementById()` it's now only searching children inside the `.container` element.